# Easy question about Gamma distribution

Tags: probability

Let a Gamma distribution (gamma(n,λ)) ,  theoretically

How the values ​​of n and λ affect to the graph? Does the gamma distribution has any particular form , or depends on the choice of parameters?

Thanks for your help

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gamma+distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) article has some graphs with different parameters as well as a 3d graph that shows how it varies with both.